# aButtons is not working as expected in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, tabletools

I am using datatable and tabletools to exports to CSV, but what I want is to diable xls, copy to clipboard and print buttons. I am using the below functionality as described in the documentation but it is not working. It still shows all buttons.

```
$("#table").dataTable({bDestroy: true,"sPaginationType": "full_numbers","sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "csv",                        
                    {
                        "sExtends":    "collection",
                        "sButtonText": "Save",
                        "aButtons":    [ "csv" ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        });
```

also tried with this

```
"oTableTools": {
                    "aButtons": [
                        "csv"
                    ]
                }
```

but no use

Comment: gr8! I suspected something like that. You could answer your own question and accept it, telling which version that was not working, and which version you upgraded to, to help other people having similar problems in the future. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using tabletool version TableTools version 2.0.0. Before I was using TableTools version 1.0.2 which causes to not to hide the buttons with datatable version 1.9.4.